# p-adic field extension of degree 2n without a subfield of degree 2?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, fields

I need an example of a p-adic field extention $L/F$ of degree $[L:F]=2n$ without a subfield $K\subset L$ of degree $[K:F] = 2$.

Comment: Do you need this for some $n$, or one $F$ that has such an extension for every $n$, or …?  If the residual degree of $L/F$ is even, then we may choose $K/F$ quadratic unramified; so assume it's odd.  If $p \nmid 2n$, then the extension is tame, so one can write $L = E(\sqrt[e]\varpi)$ for some unramified $E/F$ and uniformiser $\varpi$ of $E$, where $e$ is the ramification degree of $L/F$.  Since $E/F$ has odd degree, there is a uniformiser $\varpi'$ of $F$ such that $\varpi^{-1}\varpi'$ projects to a square in the residue field of $E$, and then $F(\sqrt{\varpi'}) \subseteq L$.

Comment: In fact, if $p \ne 2$, then the maximal tame subextension of $L/F$ is also of degree $2n'$ for some $n'$, hence admits a quadratic subextension $K/F$ by the above argument; so this can only happen if $p = 2$.

Comment: Hi LSpice, you are correct, the key here is the existence of maximal tame subextension. I understand now, you can leave your answer in the answer zone and I will accept it.

Comment: Since my comments aren't an answer, just a restriction on when an answer can exist, and since [@ChandanSinghDalawat](https://mathoverflow.net/a/338827) *did* answer, I am reluctant to do [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2#comment847722_338818).

Comment: Since it hasn't yet been mentioned, $x^4+2x+2$ is an *explicit* polynomial with Galois group $S_4$ over $\mathbf{Q}_2$, so $K = \mathbf{Q}_2[x]/(x^4+2x+2)$ is a degree $4$ extension with no quadratic subfields.

Comment: @LSpice:  Would you agree to post an answer based on your two comments above to my Questions 3 and 4 in the post https://mathoverflow.net/q/456848/4149 ?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2#comment1183413_338818), yes, it is [done](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456921).

Answer (score 4):

For every prime $p$, every local field $F$ of residual characteristic $p$, and every integer $n>0$, there is a separable extension $L$ of $F$ of degree $[L:F]=p^n$ which does not have any intermediate extensions.  All these $L$ can be explicitly parametrised.  See for example [Wildly Primitive Extensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04183).

Comment: Thanks, but I need $[L:F]$ an even number.

Comment: @QiruiLi, yes, as I [argued](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2#comment847600_338818), you will have to take $p = 2$, in which case such an extension has even degree.