# A subgroup of index 2 for a solvable finite group transitively acting on a finite set of cardinality $2m$ where $m$ is odd

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, p-adic

Let $G$ be a finite group acting transitively on the finite set $X=\{1,2,\dots, 2m\}$
of cardinality $2m\ge 6$ where $m$ is odd.

> **Question 1.** Is it true that  $G$ always has a subgroup $H$ of index 2
> containing the stabilizers  ${\rm Stab}(x)$ for $x\in X$ ?

Answer: No. A counterexample is the alternating group $A_{2m}$ acting on $X$ for $2m\ge 6$.
Since the group $A_{2m}$ is simple, it has no nontrivial normal subgroups,
hence no subgroups of index 2.

> **Question 2.** Assume additionally that $G$ is *solvable*.
> Is it true that  $G$ always has a subgroup $H$ of index 2
> containing the stabilizers  ${\rm Stab}(x)$ for $x\in X$ ?

If the answer to Question 2 is "No", I would like to consider a special class of solvable groups $G$.

> **Question 3.** Assume additionally that $G$ is the Galois group
> of a finite Galois extension $L/K$ where $K$ is a $p$-adic field
> (that is, a finite extension of the field of $p$-adic numbers ${\Bbb Q}_p)$, and $p>2$.
> Is it true that  $G$ always has a subgroup $H$ of index 2
> containing the stabilizers  ${\rm Stab}(x)$ for $x\in X$ ?

Question 3 is related (equivalent?) to the following question:

> **Question 4.** Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of $p$-adic fields for $p>2$
> (not necessarily a Galois extension) of degree $2m\ge 6$ where $m$ is odd.
> Is it true that $L$ always contains a quadratic extension $F$ of $K$ ?

I expect answers "No" to all questions and would be happy to see counter-examples.

Comment: Easy negative answer to Question 2. Take $G=A_4=C_3\ltimes C_2^2$ and $H$ subgroup of order 2. Then $G$ is solvable, acts transitively on $G/H$ which has cardinal 6, but $G$ has no subgroup of index 2. (This is the smallest solvable group of even order with no subgroup of index 2.) Is $A_4$ a $p$-adic Galois group?

Comment: @YCor: Thank you!  I don't know whether $A_4$ is a $p$-adic Galois group. Maybe I will ask an additional question in MO.

Comment: I don't think that $A_4$ can be a $p$-adic Galois group for $p$ odd. Suppose that $L/K$ is $A_4$, and let $F$ be the fixed field of $C_2^2$, so $L/F$ is a $C_2^2$ extension. We must have $L = F(\sqrt{\pi}, \sqrt{u})$ where $\pi$ is a uniformizer of $F$ and $u \in \mathcal{O}_F$ is a non-QR modulo $\pi$. The three fields intermediate between $L$ and $F$ are then $F(\sqrt{\pi})$, $F(\sqrt{u\pi})$ and $F(\sqrt{u})$. Then $C_3 = \text{Gal}(L/F)$ is supposed to permute these intermediate fields transitively, but $F(\sqrt{\pi})/F$ and $F(\sqrt{u\pi})/F$ are ramified, whereas $F(\sqrt{u})/F$ is not.

Comment: Regarding "must have": Because $F^{\ast}/ (F^{\ast})^2$ has order $4$, with $(1, u, \pi, u \pi)$ representing the cosets. When $p=2$, this isn't true.

Comment: Ah, indeed I can read at https://mathoverflow.net/q/172569/14094 that a finite $p$-adic Galois group has to be supersolvable (= has normal series with cyclic subquotients). This indeed excludes $A_4$.

Comment: It's indeed true that a finite supersolvable group of even order has a subgroup of index 2.

Comment: @YCor: Why  is it true that a finite supersolvable group of even order has a subgroup of index 2?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi It's a simple exercise (consider a minimal counterexample... use that minimal normal subgroup of supersolvable groups are cyclic). Anyway I posted an answer which arranges to contain the stabilizer, when the index is 2-times-odd.

Comment: @YCor: It is not true that $p$-adic Galois groups are necessarily supersolvable. In fact the page you linked to in your comment contains counterexamples.

Comment: @PeterMueller Ah thanks. I edited that old post to make it more clear. However, these are examples over $\mathbf{Q}_2$. Are there examples over $p$-adic fields with odd $p$?

Comment: @YCor: Yes, for instance $x^6+ 3x^5- 2$ over $\mathbb Q_3$ has Galois group $C_3^2\rtimes C_4$ which is not supersolvable. See https://math.la.asu.edu/~jj/localfields/ where one can find many examples of $p$-adic Galois groups.

Comment: @PeterMueller OK, so my question is whether for odd $p$, a $p$-adic Galois group is 2-supersolvable (in the sense that every irreducible subquotient is abelian and, if of even order, is cyclic). The above example is not 2-supersolvable (irreducible subquotient $C_2^3$).

Comment: @YCor:  What do you mean by "irreducible"?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi that, as a group endowed with an action, it has exactly 2 subgroups (invariant under the action). Each normal subquotient of $G$ is a group endowed with a $G$-action. (I should have written normal subquotient: quotient of a normal subgroup by a smaller normal subgroup)

Comment: @YCor: For the structure of the absolute Galois group of a p-adic field, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3654265/37763 and the reference to Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg therein.

Comment: @YCor: The reference is Proposition (7.5.2) in [NSW].

Comment: @YCor: So, I think, our Galois group may have a p-group  $W$ (the ramification subgroup) as a normal  subgroup, and the quotient $G/W$ is described by Proposition (7.5.2).

Comment: @YCor: We have a *split* short exact sequence $$ 1 \to A\to G/W\to B\to 1$$ where $B$ is a finite cyclic group ${\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z}$ and $A$ is a finite product of cyclic $\ell$-groups (each $\ell$ at most once) for $\ell$ different from $p$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi So $G/W$ is $p$-supersolvable. However $W$ (endowed with the $G$-action) might be problematic. Can it happen that $W$ is $p$-elementary abelian, not cyclic, and $G/W$ acts irreducibly on $W$?

Comment: @YCor:  Concerning $W$, I will ask an expert on the ramification group.

Comment: I believe that LSpice's comments for the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2 give an affirmative answer to Questions 3 and 4.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, @PeterMueller!

Comment: @YCor:  Would you agree to post a new answer to my Questions 3 and 4 based on your two comments for the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2 ?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi you seem to mean LSpice. Actually I would have liked to read an explicit purely group theoretic property satisfied by Galois group of finite $p$-adic extensions, which implies the given property.

Comment: @LSpice:  Would you agree to post an answer to my Questions 3 and 4 above based on your two comments for the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At @MikhailBorovoi's [request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2#comment1183413_338818), I copy here two comments [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2#comment847598_338818) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2#comment847600_338818) from [p-adic field extension of degree 2n without a subfield of degree 2?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338818/p-adic-field-extension-of-degree-2n-without-a-subfield-of-degree-2) as an answer to Question 4.  (The comment suggested that they answer Question 3, but I don't immediately see that, almost certainly by my own failure.)

The answer to Question 4 is Yes.

If the residual degree of $L/K$ is even, then we may choose $F/K$ quadratic unramified; so assume it's odd. If the residual characteristic $p$ doesn't divide $[L : K]$, then $L/K$ is tame, so one can write $L = E(\sqrt[e]\varpi)$ for some unramified $E/K$ and uniformiser $\varpi$ of $E$, where $e$ is the ramification degree of $L/K$. Since $E/K$ has odd degree, there is a uniformiser $\varpi'$ of $K$ such that $\varpi^{-1}\varpi'$ projects to a square in the residue field of $E$, and then $F \mathrel{:=} K(\sqrt{\varpi'})$ is contained in $L$.

Since $p \ne 2$, the maximal tame subextension of $L/K$ is also of even degree, hence admits a quadratic subextension by the above argument.

Comment: Since the answer to Question 4 is Yes, the answer to Question 3 is Yes as well. Here $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension. The subgroup  $H$ of index 2 in the Galois group $G={\rm Gal}(L/K)$ that I have in mind is $H={\rm Gal}(L/F)$ where $F$ is the quadratic subextenion of $L/K$ constructed in the answer.

Comment: LSpice:  I have edited your answer to make the notations compatible with those of the question. I also stated explicitly that the answer to Question 4 is Yes. Please check that I have not made mistakes.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1183436), yes, it looks correct to me.  Sorry, I noticed that the extension field was called $L$, and don't seem to have bothered to have checked the name of the ground field!  [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1183434), I understand how we get an index-$2$ subgroup $H$, but don't see why $H$ must contain each $\operatorname{Stab}(x)$, again almost certainly by my own failure.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence: "Since $E/K$ has odd degree, there is a uniformiser $\varpi'$ of $K$ such that $\varpi^{-1}\varpi'$ projects to a square in the residue field of $E$, and then $F \mathrel{:=} K(\sqrt{\varpi'}]$ is contained in $L$."   Could you please add details?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1183469), let $\varpi'$ be *any* uniformiser of $K$, and let $q$ be the order of the residue field of $K$.  If $\varpi^{-1}\varpi'$ projects to a square in the residue field of $E$, then we are done.  Otherwise, since $q$ and $f$ are odd, so is $\frac{q^f - 1}{q - 1}$ (because it's $q f$ modulo $2$); so not every $(q - 1)$st root of unity is a square in $\mathbb F_{q^f}$, so we can adjust $\varpi'$ by a non-square root of unity in $K$ so that now $\varpi^{-1}\varpi'$ *is* a square. […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1183473)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456848/a-subgroup-of-index-2-for-a-solvable-finite-group-transitively-acting-on-a-finit/456921#comment1183472_456921) Since $e$ is even, we have that $\sqrt\varpi$ belongs to $L = E(\sqrt[e]\varpi)$. Since $\varpi^{-1}\varpi'$ projects to a square in the residue field of $E$ and $p$ is odd, it follows that $\varpi^{-1}\varpi'$ itself is a square in $E$, hence in $L$, so $\sqrt\varpi\cdot\sqrt{\varpi^{-1}\varpi'} = \sqrt{\varpi'}$ belongs to $L$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that a [pro]finite group $G$ is $p$-supersolvable if for all [closed] normal subgroups $N_1\subset N_2$ of $G$ with $N_1$ maximal $G$-normal proper subgroup of $N_2$, the group $N_2/N_1$ is elementary abelian, and if $N_2/N_1$. is $p$-group then it is cyclic.

> If $G$ is a $2$-supersolvable finite group and $H$ is a subgroup with $|G/H|$ in $4\mathbf{Z}+2$, then $H$ is contained in a subgroup of index 2.

Proof: we can suppose that $H$ is maximal for the property of having even index. We can also suppose that $G$ acts faithfully on $G/H$ (i.e. $H$ has trivial core). Let $C$ be a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$. Since $H$ has trivial core in $G$, $C$ is not contained in $H$ and hence $HC$ strictly contains $H$. Maximality implies that $HC$ has odd index; in particular $C$ must have even order, and hence, since $G$ is $2$-supersolvable, $C$ is cyclic of order $2$, hence is central in $G$. Write $C=\{1,z\}$.

Let $D/C$ be a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup of $G/C$, so it is also cyclic of odd order. Since $D$ is central-by-cyclic, it is abelian. If $D/C$ has odd order, we deduce that $D=C\times C'$ for $C'$ of odd prime order, and thus $C'$ is normal in $G$, which we contradicted in the previous paragraph. Hence $D$ has order $4$. The group $D\cap H$ cannot be trivial, since $|G/H|$ would be a multiple of $4$. Hence $D\cap H$ has order $2$, say equals $\{1,z'\}$; write $D=\{1,z,z',z''\}$. It is normal of order two in $H$, hence is central in $H$. Let $P$ be the centralizer of $z'$ in $G$. Since $H$ has trivial core, $z'$ is not central in $G$ and hence $P\neq G$. Since $z$ is central, we deduce that the only $G$-conjugate of $z'$ is $z''$ and hence $P$ has index 2 and contains $H$.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer should be accepted. I wrote it assuming that Galois groups of $p$-adic fields are supersolvable, but this is false, at least for $p=2$.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm using only the following group property (let's call it $2$-supersolvable): $G$ is finite and every quotient of $G$ has the property that its minimal nontrivial subgroups of even order are cyclic. This is strictly stronger than solvable, but strictly weaker than supersolvable.

Answer (score 2):

LSpice [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456921) my Question 4 in the positive. Here I deduce the positive answer to Question 3, which I restate as Question 3'.

> **Question 3'.** Let $G$ be a finite group acting transitively on the finite set $X=\{1,2,\dots, 2m\}$ of cardinality $2m\ge 6$ where $m$ is odd.
> Assume additionally that $G$ is the Galois group
> of a finite Galois extension $L/M$, where $M$ is a $p$-adic field
> (that is, a finite extension of the field of $p$-adic numbers ${\Bbb Q}_p)$, and $p>2$. Is it true that  $G$ always has a subgroup $H$ of index 2
> containing the stabilizers  $G_x$ for all $x\in X$ ?

The answer is Yes.

Let $G_1\subset G$ be the stabilizer of $1\in X$, and let $K_1\subset L$ denote the corresponding subfield, that is, $K_1=L^{G_1}$. Then $[G:G_1]=2m$ and $[K_1:M]=2m$.
By the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456921) of @LSpice, there exists a quadratic subextension  $F/M$ in $K_1$, that is, $F\subset K_1$ and $[F:M]=2$.
Let $H\subset G$ be the subgroup corresponding to the extension $F/M$, that is,
$$ H=\{g\in G\ \,|\ \,{}^g a=a \ \ \forall a\in F\}.$$
Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index 2, and hence it is normal in $G$.
Since $K_1\supset F$, we see that $G_1\subset H$.
Since $G$ acts on $X$ transitively, for any $x \in X$ the stabilizer  $G_x$ is conjugate in $G$ to $G_1$, and hence is contained in the normal subgroup $H$ of $G$. Thus $H$ is a normal subgoup of $G$ of index 2 containing all stabilizers $G_x\,$, as required.